# Finding a line with an unterminated double quote

Tags: regex, bash, sed

For given file -

TEST_File

```
----------
<At_First_Sight> <isCalled> "A.
<The_Godfather> <isCalled> "A.
<The_Godfather> <isCalled> "Mrr.
<Night_of_the_Comet> <type> "wikicategory_Comedy_science_fiction_films".


Required output should be - 
<Night_of_the_Comet> <type> "wikicategory_Comedy_science_fiction_films".
```

As this have terminated doublt quotes.Also you` can assume that there will be no more than 2 double quotes in s line

```
Command - ^(.+?\"[^\"]+\.)
```

Seems to work on web based regex checker but not working on bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier with egrep:

```
egrep '^[^"]*"[^"]*$' file
<At_First_Sight> <isCalled> "A.
<The_Godfather> <isCalled> "A.
<The_Godfather> <isCalled> "Mrr.
```

If you want sed then use:

```
sed -n '/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/p' file
```